# How to config different Google Map SDK Key in one app

Tags: android, google-maps

How to config different Google Map SDK Key according to different settings in one app?

Comment: You can use Flavor and Update Google Map key at Build Time.

Comment: I want to change Google Map Key according to app's internal setting at one build time.